# Why is this inequality true?

Tags: inequality

I was solving an inequality and got stuck at this part:
$$abc+abd+acd+bcd\le a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3$$
Why is this true? I think it has a similar solution as $ab+ba\le a^2+b^2$, because in both cases the left side is rearranged.

Comment: $\{a,b,c,d\} \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Maazul: It has to be $a,b,c,d\geq 0$, because otherwise you could replace each value with its negative, and this would reverse the inequality.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, I forgot to say this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint $a^3+b^3+c^3\ge 3abc$ for $a, b, c \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just another track to the truth: Apply $3^\text{rd}$ degree AM-GM
$$abc\:\leqslant\:\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}$$
to each summand on the LHS, followed by 'garbage collection'.

Still another track {w,c}ould exploit the Rearrangement inequality.